# Crossdomain post with easyXDM

Tags: ajax, cross-domain

I'm trying to get a crossdomain post to work. I know I can easily use jsonp for GET, but I'm stuck as to how I can implement POST requests.

I've looked up easyXDM, but as I understand it the server also needs some kind of easyXDM implementation, in the form of a "cors" file or something.

Is that true? So if the server does not support it, there's no way to do a crossdomain post (without setting up a proxy, that is)

I've tried it myself with only local files:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var xhr = new easyXDM.Rpc(/** The channel configuration*/{
            remote: "name.html"
        }, {
            remote: {
                request: {} // request is exposed by /cors/
            }
        });
    </script>
```

And then do a request like this:

```
xhr.request({
            url: "http://other.domain.be",
            method: "POST",
            data: {NEWS: "true", IMMO: "true" }
        }, function(response) {
            alert(response.status);
            alert(response.data);
        });
```

But that does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, easyXDM.Rpc need to be initialized using the server cors url.

```
xhr = new easyXDM.Rpc({remote: "http://url/cors"}, {remote:{request:{}}});
```

If you don't want to use easyXDM, you can easily set up the server to accept all requests by adding : (doesn't supported by IE<8)

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers X-Requested-With
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers X-Request
```